# Pandas cast all object columns to category

Tags: python, pandas, casting, categorical-data

I want to have ha elegant function to cast all object columns in a pandas data 
frame to categories

`df[x] = df[x].astype("category")` performs the type cast
`df.select_dtypes(include=['object'])` would sub-select all categories columns. However this results in a loss of the other columns / a manual merge is required. Is there a solution which "just works in place" or does not require a manual cast?

## edit

I am looking for something similar as http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html for a conversion to categorical data

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use `apply` and `pd.Series.astype` with `dtype='category'`

Consider the `pd.DataFrame` `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        A=[1, 2, 3, 4],
        B=list('abcd'),
        C=[2, 3, 4, 5],
        D=list('defg')
    ))
df
```

[image]

```
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 4 entries, 0 to 3
Data columns (total 4 columns):
A    4 non-null int64
B    4 non-null object
C    4 non-null int64
D    4 non-null object
dtypes: int64(2), object(2)
memory usage: 200.0+ bytes
```

Lets use `select_dtypes` to include all `'object'` types to convert and recombine with a `select_dtypes` to exclude them.

```
df = pd.concat([
        df.select_dtypes([], ['object']),
        df.select_dtypes(['object']).apply(pd.Series.astype, dtype='category')
        ], axis=1).reindex_axis(df.columns, axis=1)

df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 4 entries, 0 to 3
Data columns (total 4 columns):
A    4 non-null int64
B    4 non-null category
C    4 non-null int64
D    4 non-null category
dtypes: category(2), int64(2)
memory usage: 208.0 bytes
```

Comment: Indeed this is a great start. But I only want to convert object dtype and not float or integer as your solution "brute-forcely" converts anything to category

Comment: This: df.select_dtypes(include=['object']).apply(pd.Series.astype, dtype='category').info() partially works e.g. all objects are converted. But afterwards manually a merge with the numeric columns needs to be performed. How can I prevent this and selectively change the dtypes in place

Comment: Is there maybe a more efficient way?

Answer (score 7):

I think that this is a more elegant way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        A=[1, 2, 3, 4],
        B=list('abcd'),
        C=[2, 3, 4, 5],
        D=list('defg')
    ))

df.info()

df.loc[:, df.dtypes == 'object'] =\
    df.select_dtypes(['object'])\
    .apply(lambda x: x.astype('category'))

df.info()
```

Answer (score 2):

## Wish I could add this as a comment, but can't.

The accepted answer doesn't work for pandas version 0.25 and higher. Use `.reindex` instead of `reindex_axis`. See here for more information:
https://github.com/scikit-hep/root_pandas/issues/82

Answer (score 0):

Often the order of categories has meaning, for example t-short sizes 'S', 'M', 'L' 'XL' are ordered categories (in SPSS - ordinals). If you are interested in creating ordered categories from strings you can use this code:

```
df = pd.concat([
        df.select_dtypes([], ['object']),
        df.select_dtypes(['object']).apply(pd.Categorical, ordered=True)
        ], axis=1).reindex(df.columns, axis=1)
```

In the resulting DataFrame categorical columns can be sorted by values the same way as you used to sort strings.